# i'm trying to do use function "chekPersonalNumber" in try/catch function but only works firs part of my code when "chekPersonalNumber" is true

Tags: try-catch

i'm trying to do use function "chekPersonalNumber" in try/catch function but only works firs part of my code when "chekPersonalNumber" is true. in case of chekPersonalNumber isnt true i want to perform second part (catch) in function but it doesnt.
`} catch (e) { console.log ("doesnt working") document.querySelector('#trueOrFalse').innerHTML = 'false' document.querySelector('#trueOrFalse').classList.add("false") }`
what shoudl i do? thanks

this is my full code:

````
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chekPersonalNumber();
    tryCatchChek();
});


function chekPersonalNumber () {
    let personalNumber = document.querySelector('#personal_number').value;
    if(personalNumber.length !== 11) {
        throw "length must be 11 symbols"
    }
    return true;
}

function tryCatchChek () {
    try {
        chekPersonalNumber ()
        console.log("working")
        document.querySelector('#trueOrFalse').innerHTML = 'true'
        document.querySelector('#trueOrFalse').classList.add("true")

    } catch (e) {
        console.log ("doesnt working")
        document.querySelector('#trueOrFalse').innerHTML = 'false'
        document.querySelector('#trueOrFalse').classList.add("false")
    }
}```
````